# Operator priority with operator overload?

Tags: c++

I used operator overloading for my own Bignum header, and there are some operator priority problem.

Compiler says there is some error when I do bignum+int.
(My Bignum class name is 'bignum'. Don't mind that)

Here is my class definition:

```
operator long long(void) const {
    return atoll(num.c_str());
}
operator +(bignum b) {
    //c=this+b
    return c;
}
```

And here is the case that error happens:

```
bignum a(1);
int b=1;
bignum c = a+b; //this is the case
```

**ERRORS**

> line 7 : IntelliSense: "+" More than one of the operators is
>   consistent with the operand.
>  Built-in operators "arithmetic +
>   arithmetic"
>  Function "minary::bignum::operator+(minary::bignum
>   b)"
>  The operand format is minary::bignum +
>   int.  c:\Users\Secret\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Calculator\Calculator\Source.cpp    11  3   Calculator

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is that the compiler can see two ways to add a bignum and an int. The first way is to turn the bignum into a long long and add the int to that. The second way (presumably; you don't show the bignum constructor) is to turn the int into a bignum and call your overload.

Comment: @minary yeah, much better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to make the conversion to integers `explicit`: many implicit conversions cause problems anyway. Sometimes implicit conversions are useful but if you want to deal with mixed type arithmetic they tend to be more a problem than help:

```
class bignum {
    // ...
    explicit operator long long() const { ... }
    // ...
};
```

Making the conversion operator `explicit` is a C++11 feature. Your class also seems to have an implicit conversion from integral types to `bignum`, i.e., a corresponding constructor. Prior to C++11 you could only make these constructors `explicit`. This may be another option to deal with the ambiguity but it would have the effect that the conversion to `long long` and the built-in integer addition is used. My guess that you want a `bignum` as a result which requires that there is no suitable conversion to an integral type.

Note that the question has *nothing* to do with operator priority: for any given expression the compiler determines which overloads are the best fit (roughly: require the least amount of implicit conversions). If it finds multiple equally good candidates it considers the program to be ambiguous and asks for the ambiguity to be sorted out.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was because of operator priority... Anyway, thanks a lot!